List Validation Settings rule If Column A = a certain value Column B fills in this value
I've been going round in circles trying this and I'm stuck. Formulas are not my friend.
I need to create a formula to auto fill the email address of a person depending on the choice that is made in "Clinic" column.
So, I have A column with a choice of 40 Clinics and when "Clinic A" is picked. Then manager column fills with a name.
I'm terrible at this but I need something like:
=IF([Clinic]='Clinic A', [Manager]='person')

But I cant crack it.

What is the column/data type of "Manager" column? Do you want this as a calculated column (manual entries are not allowed) OR auto-populate field BUT user can manually change the values for this column?

Hello, Ideally user can manually change the value if needed. But it needs to Auto populate based on the choice in "Clinic" So each clinic is assigned a manager and when that clinic is selected it autopopulates the column

Then it is not possible using SharePoint out of the box column or list validation capabilities. You will have to customize the list form using Power Apps to do this in SharePoint Online.

Hello, I actually have managed to make it work. Will take some time and to write the full formula but I just used a calculated list setting and dad =IF(Clinic="Clinic A","Person", IF(Clinic" etc etc

Are you using "calculated column" as column/data type? If yes, user will not be able to manually enter values in calculated column. That is why I asked you few questions in my above comments.

Ive swapped it now to calculated as I realised they dont need to manually change the data in there. Im just trying to work out a way to add multiple clinics to one choice

If you allow multiple selections for "Clinic" choice column, you will not be able to use "Clinic" column in calculated column formula. This is one of the limitations of SharePoint.

Sorry Im typing fast so not making sense, not multiple clinics on choice but one manager has multiple clinics. So instead of writing the formula over and over again I need to be able to just write =If(clinic="Clinic A or Clinic b or clinic c","Person1") Im just  terrible with formulas

I have updated my answer below, that should help you with formula syntax.

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint out of the box column validation settings because column settings cannot refer to value of another column.
You will have to customize the SharePoint Online list form using Power Apps to auto-populate field values based on another column values.
Documentation:
Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps
Check below references for more information:

PowerApps SP Form - Referencing List item value in another List
Power Apps set default value based on another field from a dropdown
Automatically populate choice field based on another choice field - SharePoint List
Automatically populate fields based on another choice field - SharePoint List


Update from comments:
If you want to use calculated column for "Manager" field, try using formula like:
=IF(OR([Clinic]="Clinic A",[Clinic]="Clinic B",[Clinic]="Clinic C"),"Person 1",IF(OR([Clinic]="Clinic D",[Clinic]="Clinic E"),"Person 2",""))

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].

Reference: Calculated Column Syntax Error
